# "Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem" no lockfile

Tags: ruby, bundler

I have the classic bundler compatibility issue however, there is no gemlock file. Why would this be?

Also, I'm aware there's other question out there however, I couldn't find one pertaining to a missing lockfile.

Bundler version 1.17.3
Ruby version 2.6.6
RVM version 1.29.10
MacOSX Catalina

Comment: Please post the full output of the `bundle install` command so we can see the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There would be no lock file because the previous developer has not included it when sending it to you or when committing to source control. Some (wrongly) think the lock file shouldn’t be included in the source control repository.

Ask the previous dev if they have a copy on their workstation

If you want help resolving the conflict see my comment.